# Turning Off Timestamp Formatting in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have many timestamp columns that I need to use with mixed timezones. The users timezone is set in the language I'm using for the front-end so I need MySQL to return a unix timestamp from a select *. Is there a way to turn off the auto formatting when fetching data from MySQL timestamp columns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` is the default representation for timestamp columns in MySQL. I don't believe you can change that on a global level.

Two options:

1. Instead of doing a `SELECT *`, do `SELECT *, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(your_timestamp_column) AS your_timestamp`, which will add a Unix-formatted `your_timestamp` column to the results.
2. Make a view ([`CREATE VIEW`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html)) for each table that does the same thing, e.g.

   ```
   CREATE VIEW your_view AS
     SELECT *, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(your_timestamp_column) AS your_unix_timestamp
     FROM your_table;
   ```

   Then you can do `SELECT * FROM your_view;` and get your Unix timestamp without adding anything to your queries.

Reference: [UNIX_TIMESTAMP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp)

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

You can wrap the filed in the UNIX_TIMESTAMP function like this:

select UNIX_TIMESTAMP(your_timestamp_column) from your_table;

For more information about this and other mysql data and time functions see:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp